# Properties of $H\lhd N(H)$ for $H\subset S_n$

Tags: group-theory

Suppose we are given a subgroup $H$ of $G=S_n$. What are some techniques for studying the structure of $N_{G}(H)/H$, especially in the case that $H=\langle \sigma,\tau\rangle$?

Note: $\sigma,\tau$ are arbitrary permutations in $S_n$. If you feel you can make progress only by imposing extra restrictions on $\sigma,\tau$, that is fine - but I am ultimately interested in the case when $\sigma,\tau$ are "complicated".

---

Some concrete questions I am interested in:

1. What is the most straightforward way to compute $[N_G(H) : H]$?
2. Can we embed $N_G(H)/H$ in $S_n$?
3. Can we make any statements about sets of transversals of $N_G(H)/H$?
4. What are the subgroups $\langle\sigma,\tau\rangle\subset S_n$ that are self-normalizing?
5. Can we characterize the self-normalizing subgroups of $S_n$?

Comment: Following Alexander Gruber's advice, the OP re-posted his question adding some explanatory stuff that was lacking from the first one. My advice now: do **not** close this question, and for the OP: @pre-kidney,  you better erase the first one so that people won't feel like closing the present version.

Comment: If you are asking about complexity of algorithms, then this problem is thought to be difficult, and it is not known whether it can be done in time polynomial in $n$. (I don't think that the fact that $H$ is 2-generated is particularly helpful.)

Comment: I have rolled back the other question and am voting to reopen

Comment: I tried to delete the earlier version of this question, but the system wouldn't let me. Instead, I flagged it for moderator attention and explained that it is an exact duplicate of this question. Hopefully it will be closed soon, and there will be less confusion.

Comment: @DerekHolt: When you say "is thought to be difficult", does this mean that you've discussed a similar problem before? Can you point me in the direction of some reference material that might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to Question 2 is no. I found a counterexample by brute force computation. Let $G=S_{12}$, $\sigma=(1, 4)(2, 3)(8, 10)(9, 11)$, $\tau= (5, 6)(7, 12)(8, 10)(9, 11)$ and $H=\langle \sigma, \tau \rangle$. Then $N_G(H)$ has order 3072, and the quotient $N/H$ has order 768. I just checked that $Q$ is not isomorphic to any of the 10723 subgroups (counting up to conjugacy) of $G$.

Comment: Thanks for the response! If you did your computations in GAP by any chance, can you summarize your methods?

Comment: In fact I used Magma. I just considered every subgroup $S$ of $S_{12}$, computed its normalizer $N$ and then tested whether $N/S$ is isomorphic to any subgroup of $S_{12}$. I am sure you could do the same in GAP - you can access a list of class representatives of subgroups of $S_{12}$ using T:=TableofMarks("S12") followed by L:=GeneratorsSubgroupsTom(T); The computation will take several hours, but it would be much quicker if you just checked that in my example $N/S$ is not isomorphic to any subgroup of $S_{12}$.

Comment: I tried something like this and ran out of memory on my (wimpy) machine. Is $S_{12}$ the minimal symmetric group that has such a counterexample?